# DynamicJasper Excel and HyperLinks

Tags: excel, hyperlink, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

Has anyone managed to add a hyperlink to an excel cell using DynamicJasper?

There are test within the src that show how to do it.... but i fear they are only for html output not xls.

EG

```
DJHyperLink djlink = new DJHyperLink();
    djlink.setExpression(new StringExpression() {
        public Object evaluate(Map fields, Map variables, Map parameters) {             
            return "http://linkInImage.com?param=" + variables.get("REPORT_COUNT");
        }
    });
    djlink.setTooltip(new LiteralExpression("I'm a literal tootltip"));
```

and then `AbstractColumn.setLink(djlink)`, this doesnt seem to work as `evaluate()` is never called when i output to excel.

Ive also tried setting the literal `=HYPERLINK("www.test.com")`..... again no joy.

bit stuck now.

Comment: Just a quick update: I think i have more or less tried all i can with DJ, Ive emailed their support to see if i can pay for some advice... waiting on a reply. In the mean time ive discovered docx4j, on first inspection it seems to do all that i need to do and very easily, the only problem im having is opening Excel xlsx file in openoffice. apart from that ive managed to get up and running with it in 45 mins. pretty cool.

Comment: Did not hear back from the people at Dynamic Jasper. So i spent 24 hours learning all about the joys of SpreadsheetML and Docx4j, super flexible, Super fast..... i love it! apart from the inital complexity of ooxml!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must have found a solution for this by now. However answering here so that it may help others. I could not find a specific fix mentioned as part of release notes but this seems to work fine with [DJ 4.0.3 release](http://dynamicjasper.com/2012/10/21/dynamicjasper-4-0-3-and-3-2-6-released-with-important-fix/).

I see this in AbstractLayoutManager,

```
if (column.getLink() != null) {
    String name = getDesign().getName() + "_column_" + getReport().getColumns().indexOf(column);
    HyperLinkUtil.applyHyperLinkToElement((DynamicJasperDesign) getDesign(),column.getLink(),textField,name);
}
```

..with the eventual call navigating to ExpressionUtil::createCustomExpressionInvocationText2(),

```
public static String createCustomExpressionInvocationText2(String customExpName) {

    String fieldsMap = getTextForFieldsFromScriptlet();
    String parametersMap = getTextForParametersFromScriptlet();
    String variablesMap = getTextForVariablesFromScriptlet();

    String stringExpression = "(("+CustomExpression.class.getName()+")$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get(\""+customExpName+"\"))."
        +CustomExpression.EVAL_METHOD_NAME+"( "+ fieldsMap +", " + variablesMap + ", " + parametersMap +" )";

    return stringExpression;
}
```

When i tried with your code, it worked fine for HTML as well as Excel.